# I am getting activity not found error

Tags: android

I'm getting an Exception "Activity Not Found".I've an activity named:

```
public class ProfileForm extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener.
```

and in the `androidmanifest.xml` I have declared this activity:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.atria.requisitionform.ProfileForm"
            android:label="Profile Form Activity" >
        </activity>
```

Can someone please help resolve this? Because of this exception I'm getting a message"Unfortunately application has closed" error.

Comment: Check the `Package` name Carefully...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileForm"
            android:label="Profile Form Activity" >
        </activity>
```

Or check twice your package name.

*Note: use @string resources on `android:label="Profile Form Activity"`*

Answer (score 0):

again config your manifest file use this code and change the activity name.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```