# "Activity not found" in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, activitynotfoundexception

I am using the `navigation-drawer` template in eclipse to do a simple Android application. 
I have some trouble with fragment. 
I declared a fragment called PresenceLog Fragment in manifest but when I called it in `MainActivity`, the log still says that

```
03-23 13:54:50.817: E/AndroidRuntime(16750): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.singtel.ricecooker/com.singtel.ricecooker.PresenceLogFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Here is my manifest

Here is my fragment class

```
public class PresenceLogFragment extends Fragment{
private TextView myText = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.presence_log, null);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<String> userList = null;
    RiceServerRequest newRequest = new RiceServerRequest();
    //newRequest.getRequestInfo(this);

}

public void updateUserList(ArrayList<String> userList){
    LinearLayout lView = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById (R.layout.presence_log);
    //LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.commentFragmentLayout);

    for (int i = 0; i < userList.size();i++){
        myText = new TextView(getActivity());
        myText.setText(userList.get(i));
        lView.addView(myText);
    }
    //setContentView(lView);
}
```

Here is my MainActivity

```
private void launchPresenceLog(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,PresenceLogFragment.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It would be great if you know what is wrong with my code. Also, since I am new to Android programming, I would appreciate it if you could suggest some online courses.

Comment: you haven't added added Activity in your manifest  file

Comment: Course: https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853

Comment: @ashutiwari4 He is trying to start a FRAGMENT using an INTENT as an ACTIVITY. This is completely wrong, refer to https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: @LittleChild thanks for the recommendation, appreciate it

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yup, I just realized that. I want to change a previously written Activity into Fragment and forgot to change this part. Also, do you know what is the equivalent of setContentView for Fragment (I want to update the page as I request information from server)?

Comment: Activity `setContentView(R.layout.something)` becomes Fragment `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) { View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.something, container, false); return view; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a Fragment so you could not call it like a Activity.
You need to replace a container view, properly an FrameLayout with your Fragment.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
  .beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.content_frame, new PresenceLogFragment())
  .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't load a fragment through Intent. You have to do it using fragment manager in this way:

```
Fragment fragment = new PresenceLogFragment(MainActivity.this);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();                
            ft.replace(R.id.yourFragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
> ```

Look in your manifest and see if you have an `<activity>` element that has your activity registered. If not, add one.

Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

it is clear.

"have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

you should check is there a  tag。

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247757/i-am-getting-activity-not-found-error)
or [maybe this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Please open the manifest file and declare like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" //your activity name
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

if this is your lauch activity then do this otherwise do this

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"//your activity name
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

type the name of your java file which extends Activity not the Fargment. Means the Fragment which creates from that Activity java file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.singtel.ricecooker.PresenceLogFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

add this in your manifest file if *com.singtel.ricecooker.PresenceLogFragment* represents an activity and if it is a fragment then you are doing it wrong. in second case use below code,

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.content_frame, new PresenceLogFragment())
.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a fragment as an activity.
You can either rename PresenceLogFragment to PresenceLogActivity and have it extend Activity instead of Fragment or you can try and use your fragment as a fragment.

Also, any activity you try to use in your app needs to be declared in the manifest ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml))

More about fragments and how to use them [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score -1):

```kotlin
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.youAc)
```